# Using part of a previous sql select in a later select

Tags: php, sql

So I am trying to use part of the results of a select statement in a second and third select after the results have been set to a variable

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT operator, COUNT(DISTINCT dupi), COUNT(DISTINCT userID), dupi FROM reported GROUP BY operator ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT userID) DESC');

foreach($result as $row)
{
  $result2 = $db->query('SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = $row['operator']');

  $result3 = $db->query('SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = $row['operator'] AND dupi != NULL');
```

I don't know if this is possible but I am wanting to do this so I can do an if statement later in the code

Comment: Write the SQL statement you're trying to generate out to a variable first and then display the value that variable contains.  I think you'll see the problem easily enough.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying

Comment: Put simply, Display/write out the SQL statement before you execute it.  The SQL you see will not be valid SQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```php
$result = $db->query('SELECT operator, COUNT(DISTINCT dupi), COUNT(DISTINCT userID), dupi FROM reported GROUP BY operator ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT userID) DESC');

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $result2 = $db->query("SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = " . $row['operator']);
    $result3 = $db->query("SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = " . $row['operator'] . " AND dupi != NULL");
}
```

If it works it was just a concatenation problem with `'SELECT...$row['`

One way to debug this kind of problem :

```php
foreach($result as $row)
{
    // You write the query in a string
    $sql2 = "SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = " . $row['operator'];

    var_dump($sql2); // Check how it looks

    $result2 = $db->query($sql2);

    // same for $result3
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you:) I will accept when the timer is up

Comment: If it works for OP can people explain the negative vote please?

Comment: I wasn't sure about that either. I did however notice the statement isn't exactly working as operator is text

Comment: It works if you just replace your `'...'` by `"..."` ? Eg. `"SELECT dupi FROM reported WHERE operator = $row['operator']"`